# Can I pass yaml (or json, that works) to helm directly?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I would like to be able to do something like:

```bash
VALUES="
port: 80
"

helm install mychart ./mychart --set "${VALUES}"
# or
helm install mychart ./mychart --values "${VALUES}"
```

This is not for me to use directly of course, but rather I want to strongly leverage a tool that can wrap around helm. And the orchestration of helm charts and customizable values would be great to be able to do in this way (the tool that can enable me to do this is [Tilt](https://tilt.dev/) btw, and it's great). I'd even be happy with json support, `yq` can handle such input streams and convert to json on the fly.

Sure sure, helm can support:

```
cat "${VALUES"} > tmpfile.yaml
helm install mychart ./mychart --values ./tmpfile.yaml
```

but :( that causes more drift for the use case. This is actually going to manage many many customizable and dynamic helm values and I don't want many temp files cluttering up people's systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your env var directly into the helm command, and read it via stdin:

```
echo $VALUES | helm install mychart ./mychart -f -
```

Here's a better explanation:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074067/what-does-the-syntax-of-pipe-and-ending-dash-mean